# Detect incorrect user login inside view template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise with Rails 4. In my sessions/new.html.erb how do I know that there was an incorrect user login attempt? All I want is to display an error message when there was an incorrect login attempt. For design reasons I can't use flash messages.

**Update:**
After doing some research I found that I can get error messages like this:

```
<%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
<%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
<%- end -%>
```

But this is a poor design if I rely on contents of flash message to figure out whether login was successful. I also tried resource.errors but it's empty. This should be such a basic feature, I don't understand why it takes me so much time to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Isn't there an easier way? I submit the form, it goes to devise controller, it checks credentials, can't login and displays the form back. I was thinking that controller should pass some object into view that can tell me that login was incorrect. It's hard to believe that flash messages is the only way to get the current state. Will check the source.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i think your question about role user. you can customize sessions controller from devise. Have you read [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos)?

Comment: I just started, it's a lot of info, so I was thinking it should be easy to do like <% if errors.length > 0 %>Display error here<% end %>

Answer (score 0):

this should work to check if you have errors under the view:

```
<% if resource.errors.present? %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
<% end %>
```

cheers.